# Android Adding Tab inside Fragment

Tags: android, tabs, fragment

I am Trying to add a TabHost Inside a Fragment ...The Code is given bellow.Here inside the Fragment I am Trying to add TabHost to show two Tab

```
public class TablesFragment extends Fragment {

TabHost tabHost;
TabHost.TabSpec spec;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tables_fragment, container,
            false);
    tabHost = (TabHost) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup();

    Intent intentAndroid = new Intent().setClass(getActivity(),
            NewsFragment.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Android").setContent(intentAndroid)
            .setIndicator("Android");
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    Intent intentBus = new Intent().setClass(getActivity(), NewsFragment.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Welcome").setIndicator("Welcome")
            .setContent(intentBus).setIndicator("Welcome");
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    return rootView;
}
```

}

This Is Giving me Error...Need Assistant with this code...

LogCat:

```
01-26 16:21:27.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5597): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-26 16:21:27.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5597): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you    forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?
01-26 16:21:27.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5597):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:692)
01-26 16:21:27.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5597):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:358)
01-26 16:21:27.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5597):     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:236)
01-26 16:21:27.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5597):     at com.fifaworldcup2014.TablesFragment.onCreateView(TablesFragment.java:31)
01-26 16:21:27.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5597):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
01-26 16:21:27.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5597):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
01-26 16:21:27.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5597):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
01-26 16:21:27.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5597):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
01-26 16:21:27.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5597):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
01-26 16:21:27.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5597):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
01-26 16:21:27.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5597):     at com.fifaworldcup2014.MainActivity.onTabChanged(MainActivity.java:164)
01-26 16:21:27.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5597):     at android.widget.TabHost.invokeOnTabChangeListener(TabHost.java:391)
01-26 16:21:27.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5597):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:376)
01-26 16:21:27.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5597):     at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:150)
01-26 16:21:27.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5597):     at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:546)
01-26 16:21:27.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5597):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
01-26 16:21:27.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5597):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
01-26 16:21:27.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5597):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-26 16:21:27.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5597):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-26 16:21:27.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5597):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-26 16:21:27.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5597):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-26 16:21:27.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5597):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-26 16:21:27.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5597):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-26 16:21:27.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5597):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-26 16:21:27.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5597):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-26 16:21:27.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5597):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I know this is almost a year old, but working with the v22 compat library targeting API17, and using TabLayout, I have been able to add tabs on the top level activity, add fragments to each tab, and then add a TabLayout to those fragments and get a second level of tabs and add fragments to those (nested).  One must use the [getChildFragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getFragmentManager()) when adding the child fragments to a fragment. I would submit this as an answer, but I don't have code examples and I'd end up getting downvoted..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe this could work for you, if you are targeting API17 +.
If not you should take a look at [ViewContainers, and swipeable views](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/).

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class TabHostParentFragment extends Fragment {

private FragmentTabHost tabHost;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
tabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
tabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.layout.my_parent_fragment);

Bundle arg1 = new Bundle();
arg1.putInt("Arg for Frag1", 1);
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("Frag Tab1"),
    NewsFragment.class, arg1);

Bundle arg2 = new Bundle();
arg2.putInt("Arg for Frag2", 2);
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("Frag Tab2"),
    MyNestedFragment2.class, arg2);

return tabHost;
}
```

Comment: public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements     TabHost.OnTabChangeListener

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Are you trying to have a "master" tab in the MainActivity view? Or a tab controller INSIDE the fragment, for a tabbed user interface inside one of the fragments?

Comment: I have tabs if MainActivity and I trying to have tabs inside fragment

Comment: Edited my answer, I believe on of them should do the trick whether you use API 17, or not.

Comment: Thanks! 5 hours searched for a solution to this problem

Comment: What does `R.layout.my_parent_fragment` look like?

Comment: @JonnyWright try following this : https://maxalley.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/android-creating-a-tab-layout-with-fragmenttabhost-and-fragments/

Comment: @iNzzane       Hi, are these tabs swipable aswell? I think i read something about tabHost not being swipable if i remember correctly.

Comment: @CantThinkOfAnything yes they are, you can make them swipeable with a SimpleGestureListener programatically.

Comment: @iNzzane       hey thanks for replying, I apreciate it! I have another question tho... will this also work for API 22+?

Answer (score 2):

checkout below code it will definitely help you if u still looking to for answer &  and it will work on API 11 for old version

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AnalogClock;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class TabFragment extends Fragment {

    private TabHost mTabHost;
    View rootView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabinterview, container, false);
        mTabHost = (TabHost) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tag");
        spec.setIndicator("Android");
        spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {

            @Override
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return (new AnalogClock(getActivity()));
            }
        });
        mTabHost.addTab(spec);
        spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tag1");
        spec.setIndicator("java");
        spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {

            @Override
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return (new AnalogClock(getActivity()));
            }
        });
        mTabHost.addTab(spec);
        spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tag2");
        spec.setIndicator("Favourate");
        spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {

            @Override
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return (new AnalogClock(getActivity()));
            }
        });
        mTabHost.addTab(spec);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do the layouts look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AnalogClock;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class TabFragment extends Fragment {

    private TabHost mTabHost;
    View rootView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabinterview, container, false);
        mTabHost = (TabHost) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tag");
        spec.setIndicator("Android");
        spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {

            @Override
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return (new AnalogClock(getActivity()));
            }
        });
        mTabHost.addTab(spec);
        spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tag1");
        spec.setIndicator("java");
        spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {

            @Override
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return (new AnalogClock(getActivity()));
            }
        });
        mTabHost.addTab(spec);
        spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tag2");
        spec.setIndicator("Favourate");
        spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {

            @Override
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return (new AnalogClock(getActivity()));
            }
        });
        mTabHost.addTab(spec);
        return rootView;
    }
}

this code how to give Page Link
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34224495/1386969

Make sure the layout looks like:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".view.user.DetailsFragment">

<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </TabWidget>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
</TabHost>
```