# Add tab in Fragment and Call from MainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-tab-host

I want to create an App, which have Navigation Drawer /DrawerLayout , Fragments, And fragment with Tab.

[image]

I want Fragment with tab and just call in MainActivity.java as

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Fragment fragment=null;
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
               // fragment= new frag1();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment=new tab_fragment();
                break;
        }
```

Please help me as I am new to Android, Thanks in Advance...!

Comment: Thanks, I got little bit help from... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364568/android-adding-tab-inside-fragment

Answer (score 0):

Hi try [Top Header Tabs in Fragment](https://abhishekdabral.wordpress.com/2015/04/10/fragment-state-pager-adapter-with-top-header-tabs-using-fragmet/) and just replace code from MainActivity and add it in your OnItemClick Method

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Fragment fragment=null;
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
               // fragment= new frag1();
                break;
            case 1:
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment().commit();
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

On Main Activity Class

```
 private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;

private String[] tabsTitles = {"Ex1", "Ex2"};
```

onCreateView use this

```
  mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabsTitles.length);
```

it callse TabsPagerAdapter

```
   public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private int totalTabs;
public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,int totalTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.totalTabs = totalTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index % 3) {
    case 2:
        case 1:
        return new Ex1();
    case 0:
        return new Ex2();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return totalTabs;
  }
 }
```